# Click events stop working when you scroll a layout with ScrollView and ComposeView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have an activity in which I have a layout xml file.

This is the landing page and thus I am migrating it slowly one component at a time.

here is my activity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity {
   override fun onCreate() {
      binding.composeView.setContent {
        MyTheme {
          MyComposableButton ( onClick = { printSomething })
        }
      }
   }
}
```

Following is my xml:
nestedScrollview
-> linearlayout
-> MyComposableButton

Before scrolling i am able to invoke onclick, as soon as I scroll click callback stops working.